# React.js countdown component shows different time in different page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my project I have a countdown component which I built by myself using Hooks, I am using this timer on multiple pages, I have three different pages where I am using this timer, I am getting livetime data when navigating each page and going back from API, Problem is sometimes timer times do not match, for example on the first page In the routing process time is `9:98` but in the second page where I am calling API again sometimes time is `10:01` it gives a difference of 4-3 seconds If I stay on the first page longer for about 3-5 minutes and then the difference is much bigger, I have checked back-end endpoint and it's working correctly, In my opinion, the problem is in the timer component where I am getting time value from props, I have not been able to find a possible solution for about 2 days, I will accept any advice. thanks

```js
import moment from "moment";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Timer: React.FC<{ expirationDate: number, loading: boolean }> = ({ expirationDate, loading }) => {
    const [timerCount, setTimer] = useState<number>(expirationDate)
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimer((prev: number) => {
            return expirationDate
        })
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTimer(lastTimerCount => {
                if(lastTimerCount <= 1 && clearInterval(interval)){
                    return 0
                }
                else{
                    return lastTimerCount - 1
                }
            })
        }, 1000)
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }, [expirationDate, loading]);


    return (
        <div>
           <p>{moment.utc(timerCount * 1000).format("mm:ss")}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must stop assuming that your `interval` is running precisely every 1000 milliseconds.

A better approach is to always subtract expirationDate from the current time and then display the difference